# r search vector of srings using regular expression

Tags: r, regex

I have a document called 'x' and would want to search it for multiple strings like string1 OR string2 OR string3 and like to pass the search strings as a vector like; searchstring <- c('string1','string2','string3') in the regular expression; regmatches(x,regexpr(".{1,10}(searchstring).{1,10}",x)) but this way it didn't work.

Comment: What is your desired output?  Do you just want a true/false if any keyword matches, or do you want all the actual matches?

Comment: Basically, the file contains multiple lines of text and I want to extract 10 characters before and 10 characters after the matching string including the string.

Answer (score 1):

```
 x="The rest of the string is actually really useful"
searchstring=c("string","actually")
sapply(paste0(".{1,10}\\b",searchstring,"\\b.{1,10}"),function(i)regmatches(x,gregexpr(i,x)))


 $`.{1,10}\\bstring\\b.{1,10}`
[1] "st of the string is actual"

$`.{1,10}\\bactually\\b.{1,10}`
[1] "string is actually really us"
```

I tend to think, you can take it through this direction in the meantime.

Comment: I don't know the API you are using, but I would expect that you would want to put word boundaries around the search terms, i.e. use `\bactually\b` rather than just `actually`.  If your code _doesn't_ pick up on the word `unactually`, then this comment is wrong.

Comment: You are right on that!! I overlooked. Not so good.haha Thanks

Comment: I'll upvote you on the assumption that you'll update the answer.  Actually, I really should learn `regmatches`; it's a very useful thing to know.

Comment: Wow thanks. You were correct. I have indeed updated the solution

Comment: Been learning all this from you. Just reading your previous posts.